# Knight's tour algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, knights-tour

So I have to write this algorithm (this version does not need to end in the same spot that knight started), and I got it to work, but it's too slow. It works with starting positions x=0 and y=0 for size=8, but if I try to manipulate x and y to for example 2 and 4 it doesn't end after a few minutes. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 8
int ruch_x[]={ -1,  1, -2,  2, -2,  2, -1,  1}; //arrays of possible knight moves, for example 2nd move is [1,2]//
int ruch_y[]={  2,  2,  1,  1, -1, -1, -2, -2};

int done(int szach[][size])
{
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
      {
         if(szach[i][j]==0)
            return 0;
      }
   }
   return 1;
}
//licz - variable for counting knights moves//
void konik(int szach[][size], int x, int y, int licz)
{
    szach[x][y]=licz;
    if(licz<size*size){
        for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){ //loop that checks every possible knight move//
            if(szach[x+ruch_x[i]][y+ruch_y[i]]==0&&x+ruch_x[i]>=0&&x+ruch_x[i]<size&&y+ruch_y[i]>=0&&y+ruch_y[i]<size)
// checking if candidat was already visited and if it's not outside of the board//
            {
                konik(szach, x+ruch_x[i], y+ruch_y[i], licz+1);}}}

    if(done(szach)==1) return; //checking if whole board is filled with numbers, if yes then skip zeroing current move//
    szach[x][y]=0;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, x,y;
    printf("set x\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("set y\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    int szach[size][size];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {  //zeroing array//
            for(j=0;j<size; j++) {
                    szach[i][j]=0; }}
    konik(szach, x, y, 1);

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<size; j++) {
                    printf("%d\t",szach[j][i]); }
            printf("\n\n");}
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help if the names were in a commonly readable language. As it stands, this is a bit cryptic …

Comment: going to add some comments in a sec, done, if you have anymore questions ask away

Comment: Do you want to find any route or the number of possible (different?) routes?

Comment: A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19214109/509868) with answers and links

Comment: Well it's different enough I don't understand anything :D I am 3 months into my first programming course. Thansk anyway

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bad idea to simply brute-force, as the number of possible sequences can exceed 10^50 for 8x8 board.

[Knight's tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) article on wikipedia has decent information on the problem, I would recommend to start from there.

One of the most famous heuristics for finding Hamiltonian Path is the following: from any node `u` order the neighbours in non-decreasing order by their degrees in the graph. Let's say from `u` the knight can move to `p` and `q` (i.e. `u` has two neighbours), then in your recursion consider initially `p` if it has less available neighbours than `q`. This usually leads to to significant optimizations, especially if the graph has a lot of Hamilton Paths as in this case.

Regarding your code. You don't need to call done() everytime. If at any moment `licz >= size*size`, then you know that you found your answer. You can store a global `boolean done` instead for example. This should help a little bit, but won't help in all cases.

P.S. If you need *any* single solution for your project, I would recommend to store a single Hamilton *cycle*, and for any `x,y` just simply shift the sequence to get a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means an answer, just an idea that might be helpful.

I remember that for some sizes a simple spiral pattern will fill the outer edge of the board and reduce the problem to a simpler one with `size` smaller by 4.

You can use this idea to simplify your problem. For example, fill a 8x3 and a 8x5 board instead of a 8x8 board (you will have to update your algorithm to look for suitable ending position).

Answer (score 0):

ile's suggestions seem good. When I implemented just the one to consider first the candidates with lowest *degree* (number of possible moves from the position) in the [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Knight%27s_graph_showing_number_of_possible_moves.svg) (approximated by heading for the nearest of the four corners), the run time to find a solution for starting position *x=2* and *y=4* dropped from ten and a half hours to one minute and 15 seconds. The program changes are:

```
// arrays of possible knight moves, for example 2nd move is [1,2]
// rearranged so that adjacent moves differ by 45 angular degrees
int ruch_x[]={  2,  1, -1, -2, -2, -1,  1,  2};
int ruch_y[]={  1,  2,  2,  1, -1, -2, -2, -1};
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>

//licz - variable for counting knights moves//
void konik(int szach[][size], int x, int y, int licz)
{
    szach[x][y]=licz;
    if (licz<size*size)
    {   static char firstmove[2][2][2] = { 1, 0, 6, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4 };
        int m = firstmove[x<size/2][y<size/2][abs(size-1-x*2)<abs(size-1-y*2)];
        for (int s=0; s<=7; s++) //loop that checks every possible knight move//
        {   static int ply[8] = { 0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4 };
            int i = m+ply[s];   // firstmove towards corner, then back and forth
            if (i < 0) i += 8;
            else
            if (i > 7) i -= 8;
            // checking if candidate ...
            if (x+ruch_x[i]>=0&&x+ruch_x[i]<size    // not outside of the board
             && y+ruch_y[i]>=0&&y+ruch_y[i]<size
             && szach[x+ruch_x[i]][y+ruch_y[i]]==0  // not already visited
               )
                konik(szach, x+ruch_x[i], y+ruch_y[i], licz+1);
        }
    }

    if (done(szach)==1) return; //checking if whole board is filled with numbers
                                //if yes then skip zeroing current move//
    szach[x][y]=0;
}
```

By the way, the original program's behavior was not strictly defined, because `szach[x+ruch_x[i]][y+ruch_y[i]]` was checked before the check that `x+ruch_x[i]`, `y+ruch_y[i]` is not outside of the board array.